# $(a^2+b^2)\cdot (c^2+d^2) = z^2+1$ then $z = ac+bd$ ?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have the following equation : 
$$(a^2+b^2)\cdot (c^2+d^2) = z^2+1$$ with $a, b, c, d, z \in \mathbb{N}$

Then how can I prove that : $z = ac+bd$ ?

I tried Brahmagupta identity but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: If that were true, then we could conclude $ac+bd=ad+bc$, i.e., $a=b\lor c=d$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen perhaps the OP should add a clause "up to permutation of $a,b$ and $c,d$. In any event, even that is false.

Answer (score 6):

The statement is false. Counter-example:
$$(9^2+7^2)(4^2+1^2) = 2210 = 47^2 + 1 
\quad\text{ but }\quad
47 \ne 
\begin{cases}
43 &= 9\cdot 4 + 7\cdot 1\\
37 &= 9\cdot 1 + 7\cdot 4
\end{cases}$$

Please note that $47$ is the smallest value of $z$ where $z^2+1$ contains three distinct prime factors of the form $4k+1$. This allow one to express one of
$a^2+b^2$ or $c^2+d^2$ as sum of two squares in more than one way. 
As an example, the first factor above has following two representations:
$$9^2 + 7^2 = 11^2+3^2$$
and $11\cdot 4 + 3\cdot 1$ do equal to $47$.

Comment: $$(9^2+7^2)(4^2+1^2)=(11^2+3^2)(4^2+1^2)=47^2+1$$  $$11*1=3*4-1$$ $$47=z=11*4+3*1$$

Answer (score 3):

$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2=z^2+1$$

$$z=ac+bd$$

$$ad=bc\pm1$$